# How do you insert into a table comprised entirely from auto-generated values?

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert, auto-increment

Suppose you have a table in SQL Server declared in the following manner:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table 
(
    id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY
);
```

How do you `INSERT` into this table? I have tried the following, all to no avail:

```
INSERT INTO my_table;
INSERT INTO my_table () VALUES ();
INSERT INTO my_table SELECT NULL;
```

Comment: `INSERT my_table DEFAULT VALUES;`

Comment: This is alternative: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049625/sql-how-to-insert-row-without-auto-incrementing-a-id-column

Comment: What is the use case for this table?

Comment: An initially anaemic relation (read: collation point) for a second bridging table. Eventually the table may have other fields, but not at the outset.

Comment: @MartinSmith could you link to the duplicate? I couldn't find one when searching initially.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25900996/how-to-insert-into-a-table-that-specifies-a-default-value-for-every-column

Comment: Ta, right you are. I wasn't specifying the term "default" when searching (I used auto-generated), I imagine that had an impact.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can specify `DEFAULT VALUES` as long as all columns are auto-generated, allow null, or have default constraints:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.my_table DEFAULT VALUES;
```

Comment: @JohnCappelletti, thanks for mentioning that. I improved my answer.